# I can't accept Notifications for my app on my Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra Android 13

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, notifications

I have this following app made with flutter which should just show me different types of notifications based from [this](https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/243/show-local-notification-flutter/#:%7E:text=Setup%20Icon%20for%20Notification%20on%20status%20bar%3A&text=Copy%20the%20app%20icon%20at,an%20icon%20of%20the%20app.). If I try to run it it works fine but it won't show any notifications and In the App info in Android I can't grant the permission for notification Android won't let me do that. I am trying this on an Samsung galaxy S21 Ultra

```
import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
     'resource://drawable/notification_icon', 
     [            // notification icon 
        NotificationChannel(
            channelGroupKey: 'basic_test',
            channelKey: 'basic',
            channelName: 'Basic notifications',
            channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
            channelShowBadge: true,
            importance: NotificationImportance.High,
            enableVibration: true,
        ),

        NotificationChannel(
            channelGroupKey: 'image_test',
            channelKey: 'image',
            channelName: 'image notifications',
            channelDescription: 'Notification channel for image tests',
            defaultColor: Colors.redAccent,
            ledColor: Colors.white,
            channelShowBadge: true,
            importance: NotificationImportance.High
        )

        //add more notification type with different configuration

     ]
  );

  //tap listiner on notification
  AwesomeNotifications().actionStream.listen((ReceivedNotification receivedNotification){
     print(receivedNotification.payload!['name']);
     //output from first notification:  FlutterCampus
  });

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
         home: Home()
      );
  }
}

class Home extends  StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Local Notification in Flutter"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
        ),
        body: Container( 
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                            bool isallowed = await AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed();
                            if (!isallowed) {
                              //no permission of local notification
                              AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
                            }else{
                                //show notification
                                AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
                                    content: NotificationContent( //simgple notification
                                        id: 123,
                                        channelKey: 'basic', //set configuration wuth key "basic"
                                        title: 'Welcome to FlutterCampus.com',
                                        body: 'This simple notification is from Flutter App',
                                        payload: {"name":"FlutterCampus"}
                                    )
                                );
                           }
                      }, 
                      child: Text("Show Notification")
                    ),

                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                            bool isallowed = await AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed();
                            if (!isallowed) {
                              //no permission of local notification
                              AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
                            }else{
                                //show notification
                                AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
                                    content: NotificationContent( //with asset image
                                        id: 1234,
                                        channelKey: 'image',
                                        title: 'Simple Notification With Image',
                                        body: 'This simple notification is from Flutter App',
                                        bigPicture: 'asset://assets/images/elephant.jpg',
                                        notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
                                        fullScreenIntent: true, //it will display over app
                                        locked: true,
                                        payload: {"id":"1234"}
                                        
                                    )
                                );
                           }
                      }, 
                      child: Text("Show Notification With Asset Image")
                    ),

                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                            bool isallowed = await AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed();
                            if (!isallowed) {
                              //no permission of local notification
                              AwesomeNotifications().requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
                            }else{
                                //show notification
                                AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
                                    content: NotificationContent( //with image from URL
                                        id: 12345,
                                        channelKey: 'image',
                                        title: 'Simple Notification with Network Image',
                                        body: 'This simple notification is from Flutter App',
                                        bigPicture: 'https://www.fluttercampus.com/img/logo_small.webp',
                                        notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
                                        payload: {"id":"12345"}
                                    )
                                );
                           }
                      }, 
                      child: Text("Show Notification With Image From URL")
                    ),

                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: (){
                          AwesomeNotifications().dismiss(123);
                      }, 
                      child: Text("Cancel Notification")
                    ),

                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: (){
                            AwesomeNotifications().dismissAllNotifications();
                      }, 
                      child: Text("Cancel All Notifications")
                    ),
              ],
            ),
        ),
    );
  } 
}
```

Yes I checked that all permissions are listed in the AndroidManifest.xml which looks like so:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
    <application
        android:label="untitled"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <receiver
            android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>


</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue recently, and I found a solution that might help you. When I encountered the problem, I added the following lines to my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
```

After including these permissions, the issue was resolved for me.